# returning a result from three tables, where the third table's query is built from an exploded field

Tags: php, mysql

Ok here's what I've got...

I have a table containing providers, adventures and activities

Providers do adventures, and in each adventure there are activities

I have three tables, providers, adventures and activities - an activity can be indoor, outdoor, or water, and an adventure could have multiple activities.

In my providers list, I need to show the activity types (indoor, outdoor and water)

The activities for an adventure are stored in a field called 'adventureActivities', recorded by each activityID with an array separator, so I'm exploding that field and doing a second query on the activities table to get each of the activity types for the provider.

My problem is, I'm only getting one activity type for each provider ?

```
        $db = $this->getConnection();

    $q = "SELECT * FROM content_providers p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN content_adventures a ON p.providerID = a.providerID
        WHERE providerStatus = '" . getMinimumStatus() . "'
        GROUP BY p.providerID";

    $this->_providers = $db->recordset($q);

    foreach ($this->_providers as &$thisProvider) {

        $adventureActivities = explode("|--array separator--|", $thisProvider['adventureActivities']);

        foreach ($adventureActivities as $activityID) {

            $db = $this->getConnection();

            $q = "SELECT * FROM content_activities WHERE activityID = '" . $activityID . "'";

            $thisProvider['activities'] = $db->recordset($q);


        }

    }
```

So this is what is returned, several times over...

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [providerID] => 8rnsvt6Q7
        [userID] => 
        [providerName] => funholidays
        [providerCoverImage] => 
        [providerLogoImage] => samplelogo_copy1.jpg
        [providerDescription] => <p>
Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc eu ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. <a href="http://google.com">Nulla facilisi</a>. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu.<br />
&nbsp;</p>

        [providerAssociations] => 9WHh29WV5V|--array separator--|ZPhq1yVV4C
        [isPremium] => 1
        [providerStaff] => <p>
sdfsd</p>

        [providerContact] => sdf
        [providerMap] => sdf
        [bookNowEmail] => sdfsd
        [providerStatus] => 1
        [adventureID] => 1t9y8jD6qH
        [adventureTitle] => Action Man Adventure
        [adventureDesc] => <p>
Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc eu ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed.<br />
&nbsp;</p>

        [adventureInfo] => <p>
Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc eu ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed.<br />
&nbsp;</p>

        [adventurePrice] => 8.00
        [adventureLocation] => Sheffield
        [adventureImage] => helpicon_copy9.png
        [adventureCategory] => wTt80TWcL
        [adventureSuits] => Family
        [adventureMinAge] => 10
        [adventureMaxAge] => 60
        [adventureMaxAdults] => 6
        [adventureMaxChildren] => 6
        [adventureDuration] => Full Day
        [adventureRatio] => 1 to 4 students
        [adventureActivityTypes] => 0
        [adventureActivities] => Bcg2ThdVdM|--array separator--|LbQ9SLmsZq|--array separator--|TflTTN0VNT
        [adventureGalleries] => 
        [adventureStatus] => 1
        [activities] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [activityID] => TflTTN0VNT
                        [activityTitle] => Snowboarding
                        [activityType] => Outdoor
                        [activityImage] => helpicon.png
                        [activityStatus] => 1
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [providerID] => rn8gxmC26
        [userID] => 
        [providerName] => RockUK
        [providerCoverImage] => samplecover_copy4.jpg
        [providerLogoImage] => samplelogo_copy1.jpg
        [providerDescription] => <p>
Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim. Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum. Etiam scelerisque, nunc ac egestas consequat, odio nibh euismod nulla, eget auctor orci nibh vel nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris vel neque sit amet nunc gravida congue sed sit amet purus. Quisque lacus quam, egestas ac tincidunt a, lacinia vel velit. Aenean facilisis nulla vitae urna tincidunt congue sed ut dui. Morbi malesuada nulla nec purus convallis.<br />
&nbsp;</p>

        [providerAssociations] => 9WHh29WV5V
        [isPremium] => 1
        [providerStaff] => <p>
dfgdfsg</p>

        [providerContact] => dfgdfg
        [providerMap] => dfsgdf
        [bookNowEmail] => dsfgdfg
        [providerStatus] => 1
        [adventureID] => fV6cMTxHWb
        [adventureTitle] => Some adventure
        [adventureDesc] => <p>
dfbdf</p>

        [adventureInfo] => <p>
xcvbcvb</p>

        [adventurePrice] => 5.00
        [adventureLocation] => retewrt
        [adventureImage] => helpicon_copy11.png
        [adventureCategory] => wTt80TWcL
        [adventureSuits] => Family
        [adventureMinAge] => 5
        [adventureMaxAge] => 100
        [adventureMaxAdults] => 45
        [adventureMaxChildren] => 5
        [adventureDuration] => Half Day
        [adventureRatio] => 4gdfgdg
        [adventureActivityTypes] => 0
        [adventureActivities] => Bcg2ThdVdM
        [adventureGalleries] => 
        [adventureStatus] => 1
        [activities] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [activityID] => Bcg2ThdVdM
                        [activityTitle] => Paintball
                        [activityType] => Indoor
                        [activityImage] => helpicon_copy1.png
                        [activityStatus] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

and what I actually want is ...

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [providerID] => 8rnsvt6Q7
        [userID] => 
        [providerName] => funholidays
        [providerCoverImage] => 
        [providerLogoImage] => samplelogo_copy1.jpg
        [providerDescription] => <p>
Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc eu ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. <a href="http://google.com">Nulla facilisi</a>. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu.<br />
&nbsp;</p>

        [providerAssociations] => 9WHh29WV5V|--array separator--|ZPhq1yVV4C
        [isPremium] => 1
        [providerStaff] => <p>
sdfsd</p>

        [providerContact] => sdf
        [providerMap] => sdf
        [bookNowEmail] => sdfsd
        [providerStatus] => 1
        [adventureID] => 1t9y8jD6qH
        [adventureTitle] => Action Man Adventure
        [adventureDesc] => <p>
Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc eu ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed.<br />
&nbsp;</p>

        [adventureInfo] => <p>
Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc eu ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed.<br />
&nbsp;</p>

        [adventurePrice] => 8.00
        [adventureLocation] => Sheffield
        [adventureImage] => helpicon_copy9.png
        [adventureCategory] => wTt80TWcL
        [adventureSuits] => Family
        [adventureMinAge] => 10
        [adventureMaxAge] => 60
        [adventureMaxAdults] => 6
        [adventureMaxChildren] => 6
        [adventureDuration] => Full Day
        [adventureRatio] => 1 to 4 students
        [adventureActivityTypes] => 0
        [adventureActivities] => Bcg2ThdVdM|--array separator--|LbQ9SLmsZq|--array separator--|TflTTN0VNT
        [adventureGalleries] => 
        [adventureStatus] => 1
        [activities] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [activityID] => TflTTN0VNT
                        [activityTitle] => Snowboarding
                        [activityType] => Outdoor
                        [activityImage] => helpicon.png
                        [activityStatus] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [activityID] => sdfsdgrgr
                        [activityTitle] => Swimming                         
                        [activityType] => Water
                        [activityImage] => helpicon.png
                        [activityStatus] => 1
                    )

               [2] => Array
                    (
                        [activityID] => dfgsdfgdfh
                        [activityTitle] => Dancing                       
                        [activityType] => Indoor
                        [activityImage] => helpicon.png
                        [activityStatus] => 1
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [providerID] => rn8gxmC26
        [userID] => 
        [providerName] => RockUK
        [providerCoverImage] => samplecover_copy4.jpg
        [providerLogoImage] => samplelogo_copy1.jpg
        [providerDescription] => <p>
Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet egestas purus in blandit. Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin vel ante a orci tempus eleifend ut et magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim. Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum. Etiam scelerisque, nunc ac egestas consequat, odio nibh euismod nulla, eget auctor orci nibh vel nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris vel neque sit amet nunc gravida congue sed sit amet purus. Quisque lacus quam, egestas ac tincidunt a, lacinia vel velit. Aenean facilisis nulla vitae urna tincidunt congue sed ut dui. Morbi malesuada nulla nec purus convallis.<br />
&nbsp;</p>

        [providerAssociations] => 9WHh29WV5V
        [isPremium] => 1
        [providerStaff] => <p>
dfgdfsg</p>

        [providerContact] => dfgdfg
        [providerMap] => dfsgdf
        [bookNowEmail] => dsfgdfg
        [providerStatus] => 1
        [adventureID] => fV6cMTxHWb
        [adventureTitle] => Some adventure
        [adventureDesc] => <p>
dfbdf</p>

        [adventureInfo] => <p>
xcvbcvb</p>

        [adventurePrice] => 5.00
        [adventureLocation] => retewrt
        [adventureImage] => helpicon_copy11.png
        [adventureCategory] => wTt80TWcL
        [adventureSuits] => Family
        [adventureMinAge] => 5
        [adventureMaxAge] => 100
        [adventureMaxAdults] => 45
        [adventureMaxChildren] => 5
        [adventureDuration] => Half Day
        [adventureRatio] => 4gdfgdg
        [adventureActivityTypes] => 0
        [adventureActivities] => Bcg2ThdVdM
        [adventureGalleries] => 
        [adventureStatus] => 1
        [activities] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [activityID] => Bcg2ThdVdM
                        [activityTitle] => Paintball
                        [activityType] => Indoor
                        [activityImage] => helpicon_copy1.png
                        [activityStatus] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: You only get one record per provider because you use `GROUP BY p.providerID`. Do you actually need that?

Comment: I've put that GROUP BY in because a provider could have multiple adventures - so if that's not in surely I'd get a provider record for each adventure ?

Comment: yeah, but every row would contain the information about the provider (could be the same as other rows) as well as the information about the adventure (which would be different)

Comment: doesn't work, I just get duplicate provider rows where they have more than one adventure, and still only the one activity type even if they have an adventure that contains multiple activities

Comment: That's because you use this line in the inner loop: `$thisProvider['activities'] = $db->recordset($q);`. That overrides the activities for the previous iteration.

Comment: please post some sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com and required output according to it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your `Array` would overwrite with values each time.To prevent this

```
$thisProvider['activities'][] = $db->recordset($q);
```

Comment: that's it, thank you so much @Deval Shah it's been puzzling me all morning !!